# Rewrite GET Variable in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress's permalink structure %category%/%postname%/ with the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The url's take the form http://www.example.com/category/postname/. I have a plugin where if you append `?m=gallery` to the URL it will bring you to the posts' gallery. So `http://www.example.com/category/postname/?m=gallery` brings you to the gallery. I would like to be able to use `http://www.example.com/category/postname/gallery/` instead. What do I need to modify in my htaccss to achieve my desired results? I would imagine it would be something like this `RewriteRule ^(.+)/gallery$ $1?m=gallery`

Edit - Current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/gallery/$ $1/?m=gallery [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering URL example you have provided (`http://www.example.com/category/postname/gallery/` => `http://www.example.com/category/postname/?m=gallery`) you will need this sort of line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/gallery/$ $1/?m=gallery [QSA]
```

1. Added missing slashes `/`
2. Added `[QSA]` flag (may not be really necessary actually).

You would need to put this rule somewhere on the top: after this line, for example: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Obviously, you ensure that WordPress will generate this kind of URLs: `http://www.example.com/category/postname/gallery/`

Comment: That all makes sense, but it doesn't appear to be working. Do you suppose WordPress is doing something?

Comment: Try one after another: 1) Add `QSA` to the last rule: `RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]` 2) Add `L` flag to the rule in answer 3) If still nothing .. and you have full control over Apache (can edit config files) then enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), restart httpd and see rewrite log (after attempting to access such URL) -- it should show you where it goes wrong.